# Change backorder text WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following code to change the text when products are in stock and out of stock, which works perfectly. But I cannot make it change the backorder text no matter how I adjust the code, it seems to be written over by the existing code.

How would I adjust this snippet to also be able to adjust the backorder tetx to say "5 days delivery, backordered"

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    
    // Change text if in stock
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('<div class="breadcrumbsstockstatus">På lager</div><div class="breadcrumbsstockinfo">Levering 1-2 hverdage</div>', 'woocommerce');
    }
    // Change text if out of stock
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Ikke på lager - kommer igen', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a conditional to the code can allow you to modify the backorder text. For example, if you wish to use the is_on_backorder() method from the $_product object, you can customize the existing code as such:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('<div class="breadcrumbsstockstatus">På lager</div><div class="breadcrumbsstockinfo">Levering 1-2 hverdage</div>', 'woocommerce');
    }
    elseif ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() && ! $_product->is_on_backorder() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Ikke på lager - kommer igen', 'woocommerce');
    }
    elseif ( $_product->is_on_backorder() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('<div class="breadcrumbsstockstatus">På lager</div><div class="breadcrumbsstockinfo">5 dages leveringstid, backordered</div>', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

If it turns out that the product you're focusing on is on backorder, the following message will be displayed: "5 dages leveringstid, backordered" - which is an alternative to the standard backorder text. It's important to note that the elseif statement should check for is_on_backorder() after verifying if the product is in stock or not, in order to ensure that the change only applies when the item is, in fact, backordered.

Comment: I have tested the above code and it works correctly for in stock and out of stock. But for backordered products the text is still using the in stock message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease the priority first because other plug-ins can overwrite your text.
Try to use `<span>` instead of `<div>`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 10, 2);
```

Then try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/

Ps: put this code to the first row of your function: `if( is_admin() ) {return $availability; }`

If you want to translate this line:

```
$availability['availability'] = __('<div class="breadcrumbsstockstatus">På lager</div><div class="breadcrumbsstockinfo">Levering 1-2 hverdage</div>', 'woocommerce');
```

change to

```
$availability['availability'] = '<div class="breadcrumbsstockstatus">' . __('På lager', 'woocommerce') . '</div><div class="breadcrumbsstockinfo">' . __('Levering 1-2 hverdage', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';
```

because I think you don't want to translate the HTML code just the text.

Comment: I have tried to add it like this (see thread) am I doing it wrong? Does not work. Also disabled all plugins and tried other themes does not seem to be a compatibility on plugins/theme. Maybe the is_on_backorder is wrong?

Comment: I tried your code on a real web shop and the string goes through gettext(). See this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dut-08QbmhlIMPHkVGDCwEDUhcA1MBj5/view?usp=share_link

Comment: The backorder text does not change. It remains the same as the in stock message. So the sentence with "1-2 hverdage" works. But the backlog one with "5 dages leveringstid" does not go through.

Comment: Have you tried changing the priority from 1 to 10000 or any other high value?

Comment: Yes no luck unfortunately. But it could be the I am compiling the code wrong, I have attached in my edit how I am formating it (in my test I then tried writing 10000 as well)

Comment: Then try this plug-in, or check the plug-in's code: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-jetpack/